# Flash + PHP to make a submission form?

Tags: php, flash, captcha, form-submit

I have a flash app, and i want to put an in-app pop up that allows users to submit information that will be handled by a PHP backend. I want this to be secure, both mysql injection wise and anti-bot spam captcha wise. Can someone kindly point me towards a couple of tutorials to get me started?

I need tutorials for:
In-app popup window
Flash Posting to PHP with captcha (recaptcha is favorable).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tutorials:

http://www.smartwebby.com/Flash_and_ASP/Flash_sends_data.asp

http://www.tizag.com/flashTutorial/flashforms.php

EDIT:
[Flex quick start guide for HTML and PHP developers](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/php_getstarted_03.html)

[Submitting data to a server](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=layouts_065_33.html)

[Captch - PHP/Flash](http://einchi.com/2008/07/18/captcha-part-2/)

http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/captcha-validation-using-php-and-ajax/

Comment: first one is asp.

2nd one helps. 

If nobody else posts, i'll just accept yours as answer.

I still need captcha